# How to use instream and ofstream to read and output a text file?

Tags: c++, ifstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ifstream in ("input.txt");
ofstream out ("output.txt");

int main(){
    char collection [30];
    while ( in.good() ){
        in >> collection;
    }
    cout << collection[0] <<endl;
    in.close();
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to read a text file in C++ programming.But it certainly is not working since it doesn't print anything. It's just a single line containing some operands. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Put those definitions of `in` and `out` inside `main`. Don't create global variables unless you absolutely have to.

The code loops through the input, and overwrites the contents of `collection` each time through the loop. When it reaches the end of the input, it writes out the first character in `collection`. It should either display what it read each time through the loop, or add each string that it reads into a container. If it's the former, the code would look like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    std::string input;
    while (in >> input)
        std::cout << input << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the original code didn't use `out`, so I left it out here. Also, when `in` is an auto object (i.e., defined inside `main`), when `main` returns it gets destroyed. One of the things that the destructor does is close the file, so there is no need to call `in.close();`.

If you want to put the input into some kind of collection, that's a straightforward change:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    std::string input;
    std::vector<std::string> collection;
    while (in >> input) {
        collection.push_back(input);
        std::cout << input << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "Contents of collection:\n";
    for (auto& x : collection)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to write the text to an output file, just do it:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    std::ofstream out("output.txt");
    std::string input;
    while (in >> input)
        out << input << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

That will write each word from the input onto a separate line in the output file. If you just want to copy the file unchanged, that's even easier:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    std::ofstream out("output.txt");
    out << in.rdbuf();
    return 0;
}
```